# How to fetch data in a component which is using StackNavigator in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, asyncstorage, stack-navigator

Here is what I am trying to do for an iOS app using react-native -

1. I am using StackNavigator
2. In the home screen, I show all the items in a list which is `get/fetch` from `AysncStorage`. This is done in the `componentDidMount()`. This works fine.
3. I go to a next screen (using StackNavigator) to add a new item to the list in the AsyncStorage. Item is added.
4. When I come back to the home screen using the back button, the updated list is not shown. Also, the `componentDidMount()` is not called.

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: I have solved the problem using react-redux but let me know if there is any other solution available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux is the best option but a dirty workaround is the following:

Home screen

```
state = { items: [] }

addItemFromChild = (item) => {
   this.setState((prevState) => ({ items: [...prevState.items, item] }))
}

goToAddItemScreen = () => {
   this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "AddItemScreen", params: { addItemFromChild: this.addItemFromChild } }))
}
```

AddItemScreen

```
addItem = (item) => {
   this.props.navigation.state.params.addItemFromChild(item)
}
```